# Structure of an object property index/lookup table

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

We have a software system with complex, deep, and multi-dimensional objects, stored in a normalized form in a MySQL database. We need to be able to *quickly* get and sort top-level objects based on a collection of criteria of the child objects at deeper levels. Users will use a GUI to construct the criteria they want to use for a selection, which then gets translated to SQL automatically.

Our thought was to dynamically build a `MEMORY` table, one per object type (loaded from the real tables), and use a set of keys and values in the memory table to facilitate quick lookups and sorting of complex data.

This is a simplified example of a data model for illustration purposes:

```
   /oPlace/ID
   /oPlace/Name
   /oPlace/aoAnimals/[x]/oAnimalType/ID
   /oPlace/aoAnimals/[x]/oAnimalType/Name
   /oPlace/aoAnimals/[x]/oAnimalType/NumLegs
   /oPlace/aoAnimals/[x]/oAnimalType/CanSwim
   /oPlace/aoAnimals/[x]/oAnimalType/CanFly
   /oPlace/oPlaceType/ID
   /oPlace/oPlaceType/Name
   /oPlace/oPlaceType/IsWild
   /oPlace/oPlaceType/IsZoo
```

A Place object has a name, an ID, and an array of links to animal objects. Animals have a type, and the animal type has an ID, name and other attributes. A place also has a link to a PlaceType object. Some nodes like oPlace to oPlaceType have a single relationship while others, like oPlace to aoAnimals has many aoAnimals. When querying against an array of objects, the query should look at each set as a set.

Given the example above, the `Place_Lookup` table might look like:

```
   PlaceID      Key                                                     Value
     1          /oPlace/ID                                                1
     1          /oPlace/Name                                              "Sam's Zoo"
     1          /oPlace/aoAnimals/[0]/oAnimalType/ID                      1      
     1          /oPlace/aoAnimals/[0]/oAnimalType/Name                    "Bird"
     1          /oPlace/aoAnimals/[0]/oAnimalType/NumLegs                 2
     1          /oPlace/aoAnimals/[0]/oAnimalType/CanSwim                 0
     1          /oPlace/aoAnimals/[0]/oAnimalType/CanFly                  1
     1          /oPlace/aoAnimals/[1]/oAnimalType/ID                      2
     1          /oPlace/aoAnimals/[1]/oAnimalType/Name                    "Fish"
     1          /oPlace/aoAnimals/[1]/oAnimalType/NumLegs                 0
     1          /oPlace/aoAnimals/[1]/oAnimalType/CanSwim                 1
     1          /oPlace/aoAnimals/[1]/oAnimalType/CanFly                  0
     1          /oPlace/oPlaceType/ID                                     1
     1          /oPlace/oPlaceType/Name                                   "Zoo"
     1          /oPlace/oPlaceType/IsWild                                 0
     1          /oPlace/oPlaceType/IsZoo                                  1
     2          /oPlace/ID                                                2
     2          /oPlace/Name                                              "Africa"
     2          /oPlace/aoAnimals/[0]/oAnimalType/ID                      1      
     2          /oPlace/aoAnimals/[0]/oAnimalType/Name                    "Bird"
     2          /oPlace/aoAnimals/[0]/oAnimalType/NumLegs                 2
     2          /oPlace/aoAnimals/[0]/oAnimalType/CanSwim                 0
     2          /oPlace/aoAnimals/[0]/oAnimalType/CanFly                  1
     2          /oPlace/aoAnimals/[1]/oAnimalType/ID                      2
     2          /oPlace/aoAnimals/[1]/oAnimalType/Name                    "Elephant"
     2          /oPlace/aoAnimals/[1]/oAnimalType/NumLegs                 4
     2          /oPlace/aoAnimals/[1]/oAnimalType/CanSwim                 1
     2          /oPlace/aoAnimals/[1]/oAnimalType/CanFly                  0
     2          /oPlace/aoAnimals/[2]/oAnimalType/ID                      4
     2          /oPlace/aoAnimals/[2]/oAnimalType/Name                    "Flying Tiger"
     2          /oPlace/aoAnimals/[2]/oAnimalType/NumLegs                 4
     2          /oPlace/aoAnimals/[2]/oAnimalType/CanSwim                 1
     2          /oPlace/aoAnimals/[2]/oAnimalType/CanFly                  1
     2          /oPlace/oPlaceType/ID                                     2
     2          /oPlace/oPlaceType/Name                                   "Wild"
     2          /oPlace/oPlaceType/IsWild                                 1
     2          /oPlace/oPlaceType/IsZoo                                  0
```

This is a simplified version of the data model, the real tables are more complex and have deeper nodes than this example. The goal is to be able to do a quick query as illustrated below.
   The queries are shown in the JSONish style that the client generates from the GUI.

1. Get all places that have a child animal that is set to a type that can fly.

   `'oPlace/aoAnimals/oAnimalType' = {'CanFly' = 1}`
2. Get all places where ALL child animals under that place are set to a type that can fly.

   `'oPlace/aoAnimals' = [ALL] {'oAnimalType' = {'CanFly' = 1}}`
3. Get all places that (are linked to a PlaceType that IsWild) AND (has at least 1 Animals that is linked to an oAnimalType that (has at least 4 legs AND can fly))

   `'oPlace/oPlaceType' = {'IsWild' = 1} AND '/oPlace/aoAnimals/oAnimalType' = {'CanFly' = 1 AND 'NumLegs' >= 4}`

In addition, we also intend to be able to `ORDER BY` deep values too, for example:

```
`ORDER BY /oPlace/aoAnimals/oAnimalType/NumLegs`
```

...would sort the places by the number of legs an animal in that place has.

**My Specific Questions:**

1. Is this table structure suitable for what we're trying to do with it? If not, alternatives?
2. If so, what syntax would be appropriate for querying with respect to the nested groupings? For example, when a node level has multiple children like `/oPlace/aoAnimals/[0]` and `/oPlace/aoAnimals/[1]`, which need to be treated as sets, how would we query within the enumerated subsets?

Comment: "complex, deep, and multi-dimensional objects, stored in a normalized form in a MySQL database" ... is your Place_Lookup table an example of what you think is a "normalized form"?

Comment: @Hazzit Please read the question thoroughly before posting presumptuous and condescending comments. If you had read before commenting, you would know what `Place_Lookup` was, because it says so right in the question. Thanks. :)

Comment: I did read it. I phrased it as a question because that is what it was meant to be. If your database indeed is in normalized form, then what you're trying to pull off here is essentially writing your own query language / search engine hybrid - and your motivation behind doing so is speed. Without a ton of further information why regular SQL queries are not performing as well as they should, I doubt anyone can give you good tips on how to proceed. It somewhat looks like you're trying to mimic a NoSQL database inside of MySQL, which "smells" wrong. Have you considered using a different database?